# Who guarantees the assignment of resource?

Tags: tokens, resources

I am confused about the [Token model and Resource Usage](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#token-model-and-resource-usage) the white paper.
If I hold 1% of the total tokens, I can use 1% of the total resource. But who guarantees this?

The block producers? But they might give me only 0.5% resource and eventually generate the block successfully. Is that possible?

And without gas mechanism, what will happen if an execution of a contract contains endless loops or requires more than 3 seconds to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I am confused about the Token model and Resource Usage the white paper. If I hold 1% of the total tokens, I can use 1% of the total resource. But who guarantees this?"

The Block Producers are responsible for making that happen, should they fail to do so and it's recognised they'll be voted out from the community and replaced by another Block Producer in the standby pool.

> "And without gas mechanism, what will happen if an execution of a contract contains endless loops or requires more than 3 seconds to finish?"

It doesn't have Gas but still has resource staking, you stake tokens to gain resources, should you have a dodgy contract which is wasteful it will eventually reach it's assigned resource limit.

Should you own 2% of the tokens you can only utilise 2% of it's resources.